# Файл pom.xml подсвечивается красным в project explorer, хотя в самом файле не подсвечивается ничего и приложение запускается

Tags: java, spring, error404

[image: Файл pom.xml в project explorer подсвечивается красным.]

Так выглядит pom. Перед запуском приложения эклипс предупреждает, что в проекте существуют ошибки, хотя приложения, судя по логам, запускается. 
Когда захожу на локалхост, получаю ошибку 404, возможно, из-за некорректного запуска.

на всякий случай скину `application.properties` и путь к папке views

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
spring.mvc.resources.mapping="/resources/**"

spring.mvc.format.date=yyyy-MM-dd
spring.mvc.format.time=HH:mm:ss
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]s

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: а вопрос то про что? про pom.xml или про 404?

Comment: до этого 404ой не было?

Comment: вы написали "`Так выглядит pom.`" и ничего не приложили

Comment: Я имела в виду в project explorer

Comment: Если Eclipse ругается на него, то обычно это связано с содержимым самого файла... Было здорово его увидеть чтобы удостовериться что в нем нет ошибок, либо же указать на эту ошибку в противном случае.

Comment: Также упоминайте пользователей в комментариях черех `@` ( например `@МихаилРебров`..без пробелов ) чтобы мне приходили уведомления... я чудом открыл страницу с вашим ответом... вероятность этого была ~0.0001%.